# showing a particular div dynamically on a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show only a particular div by calling a function though onclick event .At a time I just want to show a single div and rest all divs should not show in my web page. I have tried this through using display css property.I just want a single function which can handle this .I can do this question by making more than one function.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunction();">1</a></li><!-- show div1-->
      <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunction();">2</a></li><!-- show div2-->
      <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunction();">3</a></li><!-- show div3-->
      
    </ul>
    <div id="first">content 1</div>
    <div id="second">content2</div>
    <div id="third">content3</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what function did you write

Comment: Do one of the below solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

1. Each div needs the same class so you can find and hide them all at once.
2. The function needs to know the id of the div to show, so pass in the id.

See changes below:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="controls">
      <li><a href="#" data-target="first">1</a></li><!-- show div1-->
      <li><a href="#" data-target="second">2</a></li><!-- show div2-->
      <li><a href="#" data-target="third">3</a></li><!-- show div3-->
    </ul>

    <div id="first" class="content">content 1</div>
    <div id="second" class="content">content2</div>
    <div id="third" class="content">content3</div>

    <script>
        $("#controls a").click(function() {
            someFunction($(this).attr("data-target"));
        });
        function someFunction(divId) {
            $(".content").hide();
            $("#" + divId).show();
        }   
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: You need a reference to jQuery for the $ syntax to work.

Comment: I like your solution. Elegant. Except--some say these days that we should mix javascript and html anymore. Creating a function that accepts the content div id is a good idea.

Comment: Nice. Our solutions are actually very similar.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you could do this with just CSS:

```css
.panel {display: none}
.panel:target {display: block}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#first">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='panel' id="first">content 1</div>
<div class='panel' id="second">content2</div>
<div class='panel' id="third">content3</div>
```

Comment: Clever, but the OP did say they want a function.

Comment: if the unordered list and the content divs are in different divs then the above method is not working.can u tel me in that case how can I change the content by using css properties

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/cmporj4t/) is what you want:

```
<ul>
    <li id="li_1"><a href="#first">1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_2"><a href="#second">2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_3"><a href="#third">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class='panel' id="li_1_panel">content 1</div>
<div class='panel' id="li_2_panel">content2</div>
<div class='panel' id="li_3_panel">content3</div>

.panel {
    display: none;
}

var panelID = "";
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    alert('#li_' + i);
    $('#li_' + i).on('click', function () {
        panelID = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_panel";
        alert(panelID);
        $(panelID).toggle();
    });
}
```

**Edit**
Also, if you did not want to rely on a rigid naming scheme, you could [use a hash](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/88xz2r6o/).

```
<ul>
    <li id="zeus"><a href="#first">1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="athena"><a href="#second">2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="hades"><a href="#third">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class='panel' id="isis">content 1</div>
<div class='panel' id="thor">content 2</div>
<div class='panel' id="aphrodite">content 3</div>

var panelID = "";
var li_to_panel = {
    "zeus": "isis",
    "athena": "thor",
    "hades": "aphrodite"
};

$.each(li_to_panel, function(key, value){
    alert(key);
    liID = "#" + key;
    $(liID).on('click', function () {
        panelID = "#" + li_to_panel[$(this).attr('id')];
        alert(panelID);
        $(panelID).toggle();
    });   
});
```